# How to find a best tool / Software from experts in StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

According to me, StackOverflow is a community of experts. In that, I would like to get a feedback about a software / tool / application.

But now, I cant ask like these kinds of question in SO. Is there any way to ask these kinds of questions from the experts ? Whether this feature will be added in the future ?

Really sorry, If i have asked anything wrong. Just for curious to work with the latest and best technologies.